# Como puedo buscar elementos en un vector de punteros y imprimirlos?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hola estoy haciendo un ejemplo vectores de punteros pero al ser un puntero un espacio de memoria al que apunta, me cuesta un poco entrar en este tema y quería preguntarles si me explican porque este código no compila bien.

Estoy intentado crear un vector de punteros pedir dos pasatiempos y que luego imprima los pasatiempos, al ingresar los pasatiempos debe ser un valor numérico y debe validar el pasatiempo dentro del vector y luego imprimir el nombre del pasatiempo que se escogió pero **no sé cuál es el error**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void pasatiempos();

int main(){

pasatiempos();

return 0;
}

void pasatiempos(){
cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"-- PASATIEMPOS --"<<endl;
cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    char *vector1[]=
    {
        "[1] - casa",
        "[2] - hombre",
        "[3] - mujer",
        "[4] - primo",
        "[5] - amiga",
        "[6] - amigo",
        "[7] - deporte",
        "[8] - salir",
        "[9] - vivir",
        "[10] - Limon",
        "[11] - Jicaral",
        "[12] - Sportin"
    };
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        cout<<vector1[i]<<endl;
    }

    int primerpasatiempo, segundopasatiempo;

    cout<<"primer pasatiempo";
    cin>>primerpasatiempo;

    for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        if(primerpasatiempo == *vector1[i])
            cout<<"EL primer pasatiempo es"<<vector1[i]<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"segundo pasatiempo";
    cin>>segundopasatiempo;

    for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        if(segundopasatiempo == *vector1[i])
            cout<<"EL segundo pasatiempo es"<<vector1[i]<<endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilar no compila porque te falta una llave de cierre al final `}` que indica el final de la función `pasatiempos` (puede que se te haya escapado al copiar)

El resto lo tienes bien, lo único que no entiendo los bucles `for` cuando puedes acceder directamente a la posición del array. Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void pasatiempos();

int main(){

pasatiempos();

return 0;
}

void pasatiempos(){
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"-- PASATIEMPOS --"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    char *vector1[12]=
    {
        "[1] - casa",
        "[2] - hombre",
        "[3] - mujer",
        "[4] - primo",
        "[5] - amiga",
        "[6] - amigo",
        "[7] - deporte",
        "[8] - salir",
        "[9] - vivir",
        "[10] - Limon",
        "[11] - Jicaral",
        "[12] - Sportin"
    };
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        cout<<vector1[i]<<endl;
    }

    int primerpasatiempo, segundopasatiempo;

    cout<<"primer pasatiempo: ";
    cin>>primerpasatiempo;

    /*Quitamos el bucle for y el condicional y accedemos directamente al array*/
    cout<<"EL primer pasatiempo es"<<vector1[primerpasatiempo-1]<<endl;


    cout<<"segundo pasatiempo: ";
    cin>>segundopasatiempo;

    /*#Quitamos el bucle for y el condicional y accedemos directamente al array*/
    cout<<"EL segundo pasatiempo es"<<vector1[segundopasatiempo-1]<<endl;
}
```

Lo que he hecho es cambiar en los dos pasatiempos:

```
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        if(primerpasatiempo == *vector1[i])
            cout<<"EL primer pasatiempo es"<<vector1[i]<<endl;
    }
```

Por:es un ejercicio de clase, y

```
cout<<"El segundo pasatiempo es"<<vector1[segundopasatiempo]<<endl;
```

## Explicación de un array

En C un array es una reserva de espacios continuos en memoria. El array simplemente es un puntero que a punta a la primera posición en memoria de ese espacio reservado. Cuando utilizamos la notación `array[2]` le estamos indicando que vaya al tercer espacio de memoria.

Si te obligan a hacerlo con el asterisco, puedes hacerlo también así:

```
cout<<"EL primer pasatiempo es"<<*(vector1+sizeof(char) *primerpasatiempo-1)<<endl;
```

Como **un array simplemente es un puntero, que apunta a la primera dirección de memoria reservada de forma continua**, puedes ir a las siguientes direcciones sabiendo el tamaño del tipo de datos que tiene el array `sizeof(char)` y sumandolo a la posición del vector.

Puedes ampliar tus conocimientos sobre arrays y punteros [aquí](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#Data_types)

Comment: Primero disculpa, porque tienes que restarle 1 al valor ingresado y no lo había hecho (ya he editado la respuesta para que esté correcto). Segundo, no, cuando tu accedes a la posición del array que te ha dado el usuario, accedes a esa posición, no a todo el pasatiempo. ¿Has copiado bien mi código?

Comment: si lo estoy probando y veo que si funciona bien muchas gracias, una pregunta siempre que uno quiera acceder al contenido de un arreglo de vectores no hace falta entonces usar el * del vector de punteros

Comment: He editado la pregunta ampliando esta información

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicación

Comment: sorry que te siga molestando @Rubiales Alberto, pero quería hacerte otra pregunta por que en  este ejemplo en concreto no utilizaste los for que yo utilice para recorrer el vector de punteros?, tengo conocimientos bastante básicos aun pero en mis ejemplos mas modestos siempre aprendí que se necesitaban for para recorrer vectores y matrices, pero me da curiosidad porque aquí te funciono sin necesidad de utilizarlos=)? es algo relacionado a los arreglos de punteros?

Comment: Está en la respuesta. Efectivamente, si quieres recorrer todo un array, necesitas un bucle que lo haga. Pero si **solo quieres acceder a una posición** no es necesario recorrer todo el array. Es que son dos cosas completamente distintas, **una es acceder a una posición** `array[posición_x]` y otra es **recorrer todas las posiciones** que para ello utilizarás un bucle que hará que `posición_x` vaya incrementando para recorrer las distintas posiciones.

Comment: ya ya te entendí muy bien si muchas gracias, si lo entendí porque e echo trabajos sencillos donde ocupo sacar los valores mayores de un arreglo, entonces en esos casos el recorrido si importa, como tu dices, como aquí solo importa una sola posición no es importante recorrer todo el vector. si te entendí muy bien, muchas gracias